# Слово "скостить"

Tags: этимология

"Скостить" означает "скинуть", "уменьшить". А каково происхождение слова? Оно образовано от слова "кость"? Но тогда какая связь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По Фасмеру:
Скостить, Ближайшая этимология: Скощу, итер. Скащивать "сбавлять цену" (Мельников), Скостка "скидка". От Кость (на счетах), первонач. "сбросить несколько костей".